# Using Flexbox as an Alternative to Media Queries

Tags: css, responsive-design, flexbox

So, I was having a play with Flexbox this evening and have managed to re-create my relatively complex responsive layout using only flexbox items and no media queries.

There would be no getting around the need for media queries to make a production version (changing background images, font-sizes etc), but in terms of the layout, I have a working version which is completely fluid and has much much simpler code (See note below)

This brings me to my question; should I be doing this?

Note: I've used excellent SASS mixins by [Brian Franco](https://github.com/mastastealth/sass-flex-mixin) to simplify the cross browser aspects of flexbox.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the main disadvantage of this approach is that browser support of FLexboxes (especially new syntax which gives the maximum possibilities for 'completely fluid' layouts) is a bit worse than browser support of Media Queries. For example, IE9 supports Media Queries, but doesn't support any syntax of Flexbox. Also, there might be inconsistensies between 'old' and 'new' Flexboxes behavior that can't be fixed with SASS approach. Hovewer, I believe that it would be very interesting and informative experiment.

Comment: The browser support was the only thing I could think of. I haven't yet tried it on ie. That'll be the next step. I was planning on using flexie js to improve support, but am aware that that only looks after the old syntax. I've not really looked at the limitations of that. I might tidy it up a little and share my ideas...